# Boolean logic: why is the "opposite" of and equal to or?

Tags: propositional-logic

In *boolean logic*, why is the "opposite" of AND (`&`) equal to OR (`|`)?

For example, why would  `!(A & B)` be equal to `(!A | !B)`?

I understand that *not `A`* would simply be `!A`, but why does AND change to OR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called DeMorgan's law, and let us think about it like this... By the way, let

- $\land$ be &&
- $\lor$ be ||
- $\neg$ be !

You have a door, and the door has two locks. To open the door you therefore need keys $A$ and $B$, written $A \land B$.

Well, suppose that someone is not able to open the door. Well, then that must be because they don't have both keys, or, $\neg (A \land B)$.

But analysing this situation, if you *do not have two keys*, you either lack $A$ or you lack $B$, or in other words, you either $\neg A$ or you $\neg B$.

Hence, $\neg (A \land B) = \neg A \lor \neg B$.

You can go through the exercise with a door where you need 1 of 2 keys to open for the reverse case.